# How can len() function count the number of letters in a word entered by the user?

Tags: python

As the user inputs a different word the length of words will change so I am trying to store the `.len()` answer in a variable which is not working.

This is what I tried:

```
letter=input("TYPE A WORD--> ")
letter.upper()
NO=letter.len()
print (NO)
```

Though there is an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 3, in \<module\>
NO=letter.len()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'
```

Comment: NO = len(letter) Could this work?

Comment: For your info: `letter.upper()` does nothing. Or to be precise: It creates a string with the characters of letter in upper case, gives it back to the caller and then the caller ignores this value. If you want to change `letter`  you need `letter = letter.upper()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no string.len() function in python.
If you want to find the length of a string, you should use len(string) function.
For example

```
NO = len(letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

give letter as argument to len()

> NO = len(letter)

Answer (score 1):

Updated code for you

```
letter=input("TYPE A WORD--> ") 
letter=letter.upper() 
NO=len(letter)
print (NO)
```